# Find All Compositions of an Integer

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorica

I can use the `Combinatorica` package to produce all integer compositions of the integer $n$ into $k$ parts by writing `Compositions[n,k]`. However, I would like a table tat lists *all* compositions of $n$, not just those into $k$ parts. I am not too sophisticated with Mathematica. I have tried searching for a way to do this, but i am at a loss.

Comment: does this give you what you need: `allCompositions[n_] := Join @@ (Compositions[n, #] & /@ Range[n])`?

Answer (score 1):

```
<< Combinatorica`
allCompositions[n_] : = Join @@ (Compositions[n, #] & /@ Range[n])

allCompositions[3]
```

> {{3}, {0, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}, {0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 
>     1}, {0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 
>     0}, {3, 0, 0}}

Alternatively, you can define a function that returns the same (up to ordering) list:

1. Using `IntegerPartitions` and `Permutations`:

```
allComps[n_] := Join @@ (DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ (Permutations /@ 
  PadLeft[IntegerPartitions[n, #]])] & /@Range[n])

Sort[allComps[5]] == Sort[allCompositions[5]]
```

> True

2. Using `FrobeniusSolve`:

```
allComps2[n_] := Join[{{n}}, 
   Join @@ (FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, #], n] & /@ Range[2, n])];

Sort[allComps[5]] == Sort[allComps2[5]]
```

> True